# Cant connect to MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

so this is my code, I watched a lot of videos how to connect mongo db to node and I tried every possible way but it doesnot connect. What's wrong with my code??? also I downloaded every important thing

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your Connection URL is without a port number, add the port number to the URL

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/subscribers
```

MongoDB - default port number is 27017

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connections

> You can connect to MongoDB with the mongoose.connect() method.
>
> mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB', {useNewUrlParser:
> true}); This is the minimum needed to connect the myapp database
> running locally on the default port (27017). If connecting fails on
> your machine, try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.
>
> You can also specify several more parameters in the uri:

Comment: @MuradPetrosyan what's the error you get ?

Comment: As you said 27017 is the default port, so it can be skipped.